# Accordion in SPFX using SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, reactjs

How to create an accordion SPFX webpart using SharePoint list as backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the accordion example built-in SPFx with react which displays the SharePoint list data.

[Using React Accordion plugin with SPFx](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-accordion)

It will be helpful to get the start. You can update the logic based on your requirements.